# software to enhance video quality

Tags: video

I have a video from a security cam, and the video is not good enough and I can't see the number of a car, is there some software that could help me with that ?

Comment: You can't recreate missing detail, but if you know what the image contains (like a license plate), there are statistical techniques that can compare the pixels to the collection of things it could be (like letters and numbers), and assign probabilities to what was there.  That can sometimes narrow it down to a manageable number of possibilities to compare against a collection of known candidates if there is enough to work with.  I'm not aware of any consumer software that does that, though.

Answer (score 4):

In brief, it's not possible to extract more information from the video than is already there (the CSI effect - "ENHANCE!"). However, if the video is suffering from a particular kind of artefact (i.e. severe blockiness) then you might try some post-processing filters. Check out VLC in the first instance and experiment with its post-processing.

Comment: It now is possible to "ENHANCE" https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance

Answer (score 4):

In Hollywood creating missing pixels is done in movies, but in real life once a pixel is gone it's gone forever.

Nevertheless, blurred movies can be visually **sharpened**, although this is mostly esthetical.
I will be surprised if it can help uncover the car number.

The free video editor program [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) has many [filters](http://www.virtualdub.org/virtualdub_filters.html), some of which can be used to improve the quality of the video.

See also the [VirtualDub MSU Smart Sharpen Filter](http://compression.ru/video/smart_sharpen/index_en.html), described as :

> The filter allows to enhance image
>   sharpness with minimum noise
>   amplification.

Here is an example of what it can do:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]